Is it possible to determine the distribution?
Let $X$ be a r.v. on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ such that $E X^{2}=E X^{3}=E X^{4}=a>0$. Determine the distribution of $X$.

What did you try?

Note from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that
$$a=\mathbb{E}[X^3]=\mathbb{E}[X^2\cdot X]\le\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^4]\mathbb{E}[X^2]}=a.$$
Since we have equality, we must have $X^2=cX$ a.s. for some constant $c$. This means that $X\in\{0,c\}$ a.s. If $p=\mathbb{P}(X=0)\in[0,1)$ (we cannot have $p=1$ since $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=a>0$), then for $n\in\{2,3,4\}$ we have
$$ a = \mathbb{E}[X^n] = (1-p)c^n. $$
Since $a>0$, this is only possible if $c=1$ and $p=1-a\in(0,1]$. In other words, $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $a$.

Please avoid answering no effort questions
